# Safe to put tiles on top of two 3/4" fir board layers & Ditra-Heat?

Tags: tile

106 year old house - on top of the joists (16" on center) are wide 3/4" thick boards at a 45 degree angle, then 3/5 tongue and groove on top of that.  Putting 3" marble hex down and plan to use a 1/2" thick Ditra-Heat uncoupling membrane.

Is that enough support under the tile or do I need to add hardibacker or plywood too? I am trying to minimize height, it's already above the wood floor in the hallway.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

It does not sound like your tongue and groove flooring is a recommended subtrate to attach the DITRA-HEAT membrane based on [the data sheet](https://sccpublic.s3-external-1.amazonaws.com/sys-master/images/hb8/h61/8910015561758/DITRA-HEAT%20Data%20Sheet.pdf) and [detailed installation instructions](https://resources.schluter.com/media/DITRA-HEAT-InstallationGuide.pdf). Hardiebacker, [per instructions](https://www.jameshardiepros.com/getattachment/98adb0c7-1bd1-49e7-a9d4-a8275d29ae4a/hardiebacker-installation-guide-english-spanish-hb1710.pdf), needs to be attached to 5/8" exterior plywood. DITRA-HEAT can be attached directly to plywood or OSB so removing the T&G flooring and adding new 1/2" plywood sounds like the way to go. Schluter can ultimately answer detailed questions about your application.

Answer (score 0):

if you install over wood, you will eventually have cracked tiles and/or grout.  it is not a stable substrate.

If height is an issue, I would take out the tongue and groove flooring, and install the cement board on top on the 3/4" subfloor.

For floor, i use 1/2" cement board.

Comment: I think this answer was downvoted because it doesn't appear to take the membrane into consideration. That's its purpose. Without that, I'd agree.

Comment: sorry i meant 1/2 cement board for floor vs the thiner 1/4 which i use for was.

Comment: @isherwood the membrane would helps with expansion/contration but my concern is the floor flexing due to heavy foot traffic.  I think it is fine on vertical application.  i have seen several instances of the membrane disconnecting from the substrate.  when it comes to tiling half of the job is to prepare the substate.

Comment: Two layers of solid wood laid at a bias make for a very rigid subfloor. I admit that I know little about such membrane products, though.

Comment: OP was not specific on how the T&G was installed respectively to the boards below it, thus you could be right and that would be the best case scenario. But I feel in any case appling a heating membrane over wood is asking for problems.  Wood is not dimensionally stable and having a heated floor amplifies the temperature swing leading to more acute dimension changes. Also, it is unclear what is the T&G material, but I suppose a house of that age, that would be solid wood and that Ditra-heat will quickly dry out the wood.

Comment: Layers of wood were almost never installed in alignment. In the case of hardwood flooring, the t&g or shiplap sufloor was often installed at a 45 degree bias.